# Using call on $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried the following piece of code:

```
$.each.call({foo: 'bar'}, [1,2,3], function(i){console.log(i, this);})
```

I thought it would print out {foo: 'bar'} for the `this` value, but instead it prints the item (which is the expected behavior for $.each). Can someone explain why the `this` value isn't being overwritten?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `this` set to `obj` appear to be these portions of `jQuery.each()` source

```
value = callback.apply(obj[i], args);
```

and

```
value = callback.call(obj[i], i, obj[i]);
```

where `callback` is function passed to `jQuery.each()` with `obj` set as `this` : array or object arguments passed to each for iteration

```
function (obj, callback, args) {
    var value, i = 0,
        length = obj.length,
        isArray = isArraylike(obj);
```

To set `this` at `jQuery.each()` callback , try using `Function.prototype.bind()` on callback function passed to `jQuery.each(obj, callback)`

```js
$.each([1,2,3], function(i){console.log(i, this);}.bind({foo:"bar"}))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also note that you don't need `jquery` for these type of operations as you can just use plain javascript:

```
 [1,2,3].map(function(i){ console.log(i, this); }.bind({foo:'bar'}) );
```